# Case expression when id has multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-update, case

I want to update the table B Summary column using the data from table A.

Table A

```
Id  Brand                                 
1   Google
1   Google
1   Yahoo
1   Safari
2   Google
2   Google
2   Safari
```

Result

Table B

```
Id  summary
1   Google, Yahoo, Safari
2   Google,Safari
```

I tried using the case expression but it's taking one value per id.

```
Update table B  
set summary = Case      
when lower(c.Brand)  like lower('%Google%')  then Coalesce(summary,'') || 'Google'  
when lower(c.Brand)  like lower('%Yahoo%')  then Coalesce(summary,'') ||
'Yahoo' 
from table A 
where
tableA.Id = tableB.Id
```

Comment: Are you sure you dont' want INSERT (instead of UPDATE)?

Comment: Which sql dialect? Some offer aggregation functions for `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

**For mySQL** see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/on8nZpFUSgV3o4UCJYuioc/0#&togetherjs=pONBCI8HMG)

```
update tableB
inner join
  (select id, group_concat(distinct Brand) as brand from tableA
  group by id) as t1 on t1.id = tableB.id
set summary = t1.brand;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work in any database:

```
update B  
    set summary = (summary ||
                   (select replace(trim(max(case when lower(c.Brand) like lower('%Google%') then 'Google ' else ''
                                            end) ||
                                        max(case when lower(c.Brand) like lower('%Yahoo%') then 'Yahoo ' else ''
                                            end) ||
                                        max(case when lower(c.Brand) like lower('%Safari%') then 'Safari ' else ''
                                            end)
                                       ), ' ', ','
                                   )
                    from A 
                    where A.Id = B.Id
                   )
                  );
```